# How do I compile against local file in gradle?

Tags: gradle

For each sub-project in our build, we have a structure like this:

```
apply from: '../dependencies.gradle'

dependencies {
    ... omitting other dependencies ...

    compile libraries.poi
}
```

These libraries are defined in `dependencies.gradle`, which looks like this:

```
ext.libraries = [
  ... omitting other libraries ...

  poi: [
    'poi:poi:3.9.custom.1',
    'poi:poi-ooxml:3.9.custom.1',
    'poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.9.custom.0',
    'poi:poi-scratchpad:3.9.custom.0',
  ],

  ... omitting other libraries ...
]
```

A few days ago I wanted to try something against a nightly build of POI. Nightly builds don't go into their repository, so I'm forced to try and get it to work with local files.

Looking in the docs, you're supposed to use `files(...)` for this, so I tried this:

```
  poi: [
    files('/path/to/poi-3.14-beta1/poi-3.14-beta1-20151027.jar'),
    files('/path/to/poi-3.14-beta1/poi-3.14-ooxml-20151027.jar'),
    files('/path/to/poi-3.14-beta1/poi-3.14-ooxml-schemas-20151027.jar'),
    files('/path/to/poi-3.14-beta1/poi-3.14-scratchpad-20151027.jar'),
  ],
```

When I run this, I get an error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'product'.
> Cannot convert the provided notation to an object of type     ModuleVersionSelector: file collection.
  The following types/formats are supported:
    - Instances of ModuleVersionSelector.
    - String or CharSequence values, for example 'org.gradle:gradle-core:1.0'.
    - Maps, for example [group: 'org.gradle', name:'gradle-core', version: '1.0'].
    - Collections or arrays of any other supported format. Nested collections/arrays will be flattened.
```

So really it seems like `files()` does not actually work, as it doesn't return one of the things listed here.

What is the correct way to do it? (Assuming it's even possible!)

**Edit: More information**

Now that I updated to Gradle 2.8, I get a line number pointing at the problem. It points at some custom build code which we put in to work around Gradle sucking at dependency resolution:

```
  resolutionStrategy {
    libraries.each {
      libraryName, libraryList ->
        libraryList.each {
          library -> force library        //  this line
        }
    }

    failOnVersionConflict()
  }
```

So I take it the problem is that force doesn't support all the same things that other methods support?

Comment: With gradle 2.8 it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Compiling using your list of list of files works also in gradle 2.5. However it might be a similar problem to https://discuss.gradle.org/t/why-cant-i-add-dependencies-created-with-the-dependencyhandler-to-a-configuration/3471 . File dependencies don't have version information and it looks like you need GAV coordinates somewhere in your script

Comment: Interesting.. we're on 2.7. Maybe they broke it and then fixed it again.

Comment: Same result on 2.8, except it gives me a line number, which is at least a lead I can investigate!

Answer (score 1):

My crap workaround for a workaround is to filter out elements of type `FileCollection`:

```
  resolutionStrategy {
    libraries.each { libraryName, libraryList ->
      [libraryList].flatten()
                   .findAll { library ->
                     !(library instanceof FileCollection)
                   }
                   .each { library -> force library }
    }

    failOnVersionConflict()
  }
```

Maybe there is a better way.